# Mongodb comparing using a field with another field in an array of Objects

Tags: mongodb

I have the below structure for my collection:

```
{  
   "price":123,  
   "totalPrices": [
      {
         "totPrice":123
      }
   ]  
}
```

I am trying to query for all the documents in my collection where price is not equals to totalPrice.totPrice (so above should ***not*** be returned).

But it keeps returning the documents which have equal prices as well (such as above sample).

This is the query I'm using:

```
{   
    $where : "this.price!== this.totalPrices.totPrice",  
    totalPrice:{$size:1}  
}
```

What am I doing wrong :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to match the size of the array `totalPrices` is equal to 1. Second, you need to unwind the `totalPrices`, since it's an array field. Last, you should match the equality of `price` and `totalPrices.totPrice`. Try the below code:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $eq: [
          {
            $size: "$totalPrices"
          },
          1
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$totalPrices"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          "$price",
          "$totalPrices.totPrice"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayGroundLink](https://mongoplayground.net/p/87aPcSN-Y7l)